# When a property of a model is a huge text

Tags: python, database, django-models, modeling, large-data

If a model in an application has a very large(in size) text property
and even longtext would not be able to contain it, one possible way to store it seems to store it in a text file and use the text location as field of the database. However I am not sure with such a strategy what would be proper for naming this property?

For example suppose we have:

```
class Novel(models.Model):
    ???? = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Should I name this property novel_text or novel_text_path?
And is this a proper way of storing huge texts?

I hope this doesn't seem as a silly question.

Thanks.

Comment: Name it what it is, as descriptively and accurately as possible without becoming verbose. This will make it infinitely easier for others to work with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store this text in a separate file I would recommend to name it novel_text_file or something similar to make it as clear and logical as possible and as Pratik wrote I would use Django's filefield.

But I don't think this is the best solution for storing data like this. Imagine if you need to scale up your system. Storing data in files make it significantly harder. You have to sync files to all server or share them.

One possible solution is using MongoDB's GridFS. This might be useful: http://django-mongodb.org/topics/gridfs.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Django's [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#textfield) ? It has been made for cases in which you have to store long texts.

Comment: My question is more about the software engineering approach rather than a possible solution with a framework though thanks alot.

Comment: +1. The simplest solution is the best one. Plus storing it as actual data in the database gives you way more functionality (searches, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You should name it similar to `file_path` since that is what it is. Also use [Django Model FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you will see he intends to store a file : `store it in a text file and use the text location as field of the database`

Comment: I get that, my point is, to the person accessing the database, the name `file_path` means nothing. What file? It's a file, sure, but what is in it? That is the more pressing issue.

Comment: That's why I said `similar to file_path` which is the answer he was looking for. `Similar to` when applied to this case would be `novel_file_path`. I'm sure a person reading that would understand what it means.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I didn't, so that assumption seems flawed to me.